# How to auto arrange height width media file inside HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, django

I have multiple files contain photo and video also. I want the file to auto adjust without creating the list of files and show a proper display with proper adjustment like Facebook or Instagram. I would be grateful for any help.
here is the output of my code where which I want to adjust the file.
[image]

**HTML** :

```
<div class="col-lg-12" id="post-box">
    {% for object in newss %}
    <div class="hpanel blog-box">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <div class="media clearfix">
                <a class="pull-left">
                    <img src="{{ object.author.profile.image.url }}" alt="profile-picture">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-image" id="media-output">
            {% for i in object.filemodel_set.all %}

            {% if ".jpeg" in i.file.url or ".jpg" in i.file.url or ".png" in i.file.url %}
            <img src="{{i.file.url}}" alt="article" class="img-responsive card-img-top">
            {% endif %}

            {% if ".mp4" in i.file.url or ".mpeg" in i.file.url or ".mov" in i.file.url %}
            <video class="afterglow" id="myvideo" width="1280" height="720" data-volume=".5">
                <source type="video/mp4" src="{{i.file.url}}#t=0.9" />
            </video>
            {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="title">
                <a href="{% url 'news-detail' pk=object.pk %}">
                    <h4>{{ object.title|slice:":100" }}</h4>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

for making a responsive view you need to add css rules and adding the required height and width + the max width of the devices screen .  when you resize the webpage the images will be resized as well

```
  @media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    .img-responsive {
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
    }
```

Comment: i want to avoid list like this example  https://i.stack.imgur.com/iuW67.png your code is not working like this can you check it again?